# Chrome blocks default browser shortcuts if they are used by an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which is used to cancel unintended video rewind. I use `Ctrl + Z` as the most common shortcut for cancel.
The extension is running fine, it reacts to the shortcut, it does what it is intended to do on user input.

The issue is that `Ctrl + Z` became an extension-specific shortcut. It only works as command for my extension. For example, it does not cancel input in text areas all across the Chrome, not only on web pages, but on the adress bar as well.

While I understand that this behavior is made to avoid ambiguity, I expected the extension and its shortcuts to work only on YouTube, as the extension only has access to its pages.

Here is the part of my `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts":
  [
    {
          "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
          "js": ["contentscript.js"],
          "all_frames": true,
          "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
```

I want to use `Ctrl + Z` as the extension shortcut only on YouTube pages, while using it as default cancel shortcut on other pages. Undortunately, I haven't found a solution. Is there any workaround to do that?

If you need more code examples, you can find full source [on GitHub](https://github.com/Likbjorn/ytcancel) (it's quite tiny).

Comment: I assume you're using `commands` in manifest.json in which case it's how the API works, there's nothing you can do about it except not using it at all. Simply use a standard DOM event listener in a content script that runs on youtube URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `commands` in `manifest.json` without getting selected shortcut blocked for other actions (thanks to wOxxOm).

However, shortcuts can be easily defined using `document.addEventListener`. In my case, it looks like follows:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === 'KeyZ') {
        undo();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not support shortcut customisation by default, like `commands` way does, but it works.